# python/pandas way to drop rows from dataframe given a start point

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner to pandas and I was wondering what the best implementation would be to if given a start point to drop the all the rows that come before said start point.

ex:

```
df:
      a  b  c  d
name            
aa    1  1  1  1
bb    0  0  0  0
cc    1  0  1  0
dd    0  0  0  0
ee    1  1  1  1
```

and I would want the end result to be if given cc as start point

```
df2:
      a  b  c  d
name            
cc    1  0  1  0
dd    0  0  0  0
ee    1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for select from start point to end:

```
df = df.loc['cc':]
print (df)
    a  b  c  d
cc  1  0  1  0
dd  0  0  0  0
ee  1  1  1  1
```

If possible duplicated values and need select by first value:

```
print (df)
    a  b  c  d
aa  1  1  1  1
bb  0  0  0  0
cc  1  0  1  0
dd  0  0  0  0
cc  1  1  1  1

pos = df.index.get_loc('cc').argmax()
#alternative
#pos = df.index.searchsorted('cc')
df = df.iloc[pos:]
print (df)
    a  b  c  d
cc  1  0  1  0
dd  0  0  0  0
cc  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given Data:

```
data = {'a': [1,0,1,0,1], 
    'b': [1,0,0,0,1], 
    'c': [1,0,1,0,1],
    'd': [1,0,0,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'])
```

You can also use index number:

```
print(df[2:])

    a   b   c   d
cc  1   0   1   0
dd  0   0   0   0
ee  1   1   1   1

#keep top 3
print(df[:3])

    a   b   c   d
aa  1   1   1   1
bb  0   0   0   0
cc  1   0   1   0

#drop bottom 3
print(df[:-3])  

    a   b   c   d
aa  1   1   1   1
bb  0   0   0   0

#drop selected (drop first row)
df.drop(df.index[0])

    a   b   c   d
bb  0   0   0   0
cc  1   0   1   0
dd  0   0   0   0
ee  1   1   1   1
```